# custom metatype for type hinting

Tags: python, python-3.x, generics, type-hinting

I am trying to define a custom metatype to use for typehinting. For example

```
print(Tuple[int, str, bool])
print(CustomType[int, str, bool])
```

the first line works fine, obviously. How would I implement `CustomType`, so that it works too? I tried this:

```
class CustomType(Tuple):
    pass
```

and get the error `TypeError: __main__.CustomType is not a generic class`.
My goal is to have a specialization of Tuple with an additional classmethod

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can do this but in a restrained form, I don't think you can specify a variable number of arguments but, rather, specify the exact number of args.

You'll need to provide some type variables to `Tuple` when you provide it as a base class:

```
from typing import Tuple, TypeVar
T1, T2, T3 = TypeVar('T1'), TypeVar('T2'), TypeVar('T3')

class CustomType(Tuple[T1, T2, T3]): 
    pass

print(CustomType[int, str, bool])
# __main__.CustomType[int, str, bool]
```

This can now have `3` types attached to it, you'll need to create custom type with `CustomType(Tuple[T1, T2])` for `2` types, and so on.

As an aside, support for subclassing `Tuple` (and `Callable`) was added in [Issue 299](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/299) and is available for `3.6+`.